# jQuery execute PHP file and add/remove class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to create a voting script for my website,
I have the below php

```
<?php
echo "<form id=\"$id\" action=\"javascript:updateId()\">";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$id\" value=\"1\">";
echo "<button type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" class=\"far fa-heart\"></button>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

The **$id** is a result of a sql query, so I have 50 forms with unique $id

and trying to run the vote.php with the below

```
<script>
function updateId()
{
    const form = document.getElementById('#' + id);
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('name', form.name.value);

    fetch('./vote.php', {method: 'POST', body: data}).then(response => {
        if (!response.ok){
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
        }
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));

}
</script>
```

Any help would be really appricated

Comment: please tell what error you are facing

Comment: Please edit your question to include what actually happens when you run your code. You also need to include any debugging you've done (like checking the console for errors, checked the network tab in the browser to see the request/response, checked the web servers error log etc)

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense either. Do you really want a bunch of forms that will always just send the hard coded value `1` to `vote.php`?  Then why even have a form or generate id´s? Without a proper explanation or seeing what the PHP code actually expects, this question is way too unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Better pass the `id` as a function parameter of your `updateId()`. Also couple of mistakes:

- use `getElementById` without `#`;
- if you want to access some form element, you need to access if by name value itself, i.e. it should be `name="name"`; probably you want there `id` value, but if you pass it as a parameter, then this hidden field is not needed. however, I've left it as is because I'm not sure what value you need there actually.

```
<?php
    echo "<form id=\"$id\" action=\"javascript:updateId($id)\">";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"name\" value=\"1\">";
    echo "<button type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\">Submit</button>";
    echo "</form>";
?>

<script>
    function updateId(id) {
        const form = document.getElementById(id);
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('name', form.name.value);

        fetch('./vote.php', {method: 'POST', body: data}).then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
            }
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know, but I would be surprised if this is what the OP actually wants. This would create a bunch of forms that would only post the same hard coded value `1` to the `vote.php`-end point. I suspect that they are missing some data here. If not, then the form is completely pointless.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, agree, but just because it was not specified, I put it like that. You are right that sending always `1` is more or less useless, but I assume this is just an example, the real use case might be different.